# How to use Map.TryFind?

Tags: f#

When I run the code below I get an error. I am using Map.TryFind and its not working. In console, I get a red line under `familyinc.TryFind(tract)` and the error below.

```
let data =
    seq { for (state,work) in statecsv do
            let (family,income) = familyinc.TryFind(state) 
            let fam =
                match fam with 
                | Some x -> x
                | None -> "Not a Record"
            let inc = 
                match inc with 
                | Some x -> x
                | None -> "Not an income"
            yield (state,work,inc,fam)
    }
```

The ERROR:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    ''a * 'b'    
but here has type
    '(string * decimal) option'
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: what should happen if the map doesn't contain the key you're looking for? And how would the compiler know to make it happen?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin so what does this error mean?

Comment: @s952163 that's not what the error means at all.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I was replying to the OP's comment: `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`  `so what does this error mean?` Not to the Question above. You're right it's a bit confusing.  So I will delete it.

Comment: my question `so what does this error mean` was referring to the error in the question. I know what `the given key was not present in the dictionary` means

Comment: The error in the original question also means what it says, you are trying to process a tuple of two types, that's (a * b), but instead your passing in an option (a * b), a tuple of two types that can have a value (Some "A", 10M) or maybe not: None. ("A", 10M) is not Some ("A", 10M). Anyway, see the answer below on how to deal with it. To be exact, you are actually doing pattern matching in this line: `let (code, resRatio) = csvfile2.TryFind(tract)`. But TryFind will return `Some (code, resRatio)` or could return None.

Comment: @johnLaw, yes. you could use `Seq.choose`, or you could pattern match. See the answer below.

Comment: you should read the comment. Id is the identity function, built in,  it returns itself so this means applying choose to whatever is piped into it.

Comment: use a match expression, I show that example as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173269/discussion-between-johnlaw-and-s952163).

Comment: Seriously, what's the point deleting the code from your question? Now answers people spent their time on are without context!

Comment: @JohnLaw - I've restored your question to the state it was before you deleted your code. You shouldn't do that: on Stack Overflow, it doesn't matter if the code in the question turns out to be incorrect. But it DOES matter, a lot, that the answers match what's in the question. By removing a lot of the sample code from your question, you were breaking that unwritten rule. In the future, feel free to edit your questions for clarity or to add additional information, but please don't ever *remove* whole chunks of the question like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the edited question:** The problem is the same as in the previous one, you are pattern matching on a tuple while you are binding an option. You should do something like this instead:

```
// Bind the whole option
let result = familyinc.TryFind(state)

// Pattern match on it
match result with
| Some (family , income) -> yield (state,work,family,income)
| None -> yield (state,work,"Not a Record","Not an Income")
```

Of course you could also do `match familyinc.TryFind(tract) with`, there's no need to bind to variable here.

---

The issue is you are pattern matching on the result of [`Map.TryFind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/map.tryfind%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-method-%5bfsharp%5d) as if it would return a tuple but it actually returns an `option` as it may fail to find they key you are looking for.

Comment: is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: It's not something you fix rather something you handle. You decided to use `Map.TryFind()` which means you expect that sometimes the key will not be found. Now you have to decide how your code should behave in both cases. If you don't know how to deal with `option`, I suggest you read this [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/).

Comment: I have updated the question and code, can you please provide an example on how to fix this. I understand why it's occurring and I read the article but it was not helpful in this case.

Comment: With your updated code, I now understand which part is blocking you, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In all FP languages understanding option types and pattern matching is essential. In fact both of these features make FP a superior alternative to OO languages. Using option types you can avoid getting `null` exceptions, using pattern matching you can deconstruct values. In this case you can filter out non-existing keys, and convert the `option` result into normal values:

```
//create test dictionary
let map1 = [("a",1); ("b",2);("c",3)] |> Map.ofList

//list of keys, "d" doesn't exist in the dictionary/map
let keys = ["a";"b";"d"]

keys
|> List.map (fun x -> map1.[x])
//System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

keys
|> List.map (fun x -> map1.TryFind(x))
//You get back a string option list, with the last element missing as the key "d" doesn't exist
//val it : int option list = [Some 1; Some 2; None]

//Method A: filter out the none existing items
keys
|> List.map (fun x -> map1.TryFind(x))
|> List.choose id  //choose will get rid of the Nones and return the actual value, not the option. id is the identity function. 

//Method B: replace the None with some default value, and also get rid of the option
//Let's say you replace each non existing value with 999
keys
|> List.map (fun x -> map1.TryFind(x))
|> List.map (Option.defaultValue 999)
//val it : int list = [1; 2; 999]

//In general if necessary you can always pattern match
let myOption1 = Some "A"
let myOption2 = None

match myOption1 with
| Some x -> x //try matching whatever is in myOption1 and returns the x portion of Some x, in this case "A"
| None -> "No value"
//val it : string = "A"

match myOption2 with 
| Some x -> x
| None -> "No value" //since the value of myOption2 is None, Some x won't match, None will match, and return "No value"
//val it : string = "No value"
```