# How to use Map.TryFind on a specific field?

Tags: f#

So I am mapping data to a record which is shown at the bottom. But the problem is the line of code specified below. I am trying to index a map and return a single field within that map using the function Map.TryFind, but it is outputing the error:

```
Practice2.fsx(299,49): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GrossIncome' is not defined.
```

How would I go about doing this successfully? Code of the types being used is below.

```
type GeneralInfo =
    { State : State
      GrossIncome : int }

type FamilyFile = 
    { State : State
      Pets : int
      NumberofChildren : int
      NumberofMembers : int }

type AllData = 
    { State = State
      Month = Month
      Pets  = int
      Children = int
      GrossIncome = int Option }
```

Example of `familyMap` and `generalMap`:

```
let generalinfo =
   GeneralCsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> 
        { State = row.State |> State
          GrossIncome = row.income })

let generalMap =
    generalinfo
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.State,x)
    |> Map.ofSeq

let familyparse=
    FamilyCsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> 
        { State = row.State |> State
          Pets = row.pets
          NumberofChildren = row.children
          NumberofMembers = row.familymem  })

let familyMap =
    familyparse
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.State,x)
    |> Map.ofSeq

let mapfunc =
    dataMap
    |> Seq.ofList
    |> Seq.map(fun (state,rows) ->
        { State = state
          Month = rows.Month
          Pets = familyMap.[state].Pets
          Children = familyMap.[state].NumberofChildren 
          GrossIncome = generalMap.TryFind(state).GrossIncome <-- Problem Line
          Family = familyMap.[state].NumberofMembers
        })
    |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: Could you please provide code that demonstrate precisely the error you are having? The given code contains too many undefined parts for us to be able to figure out what's going on...

Comment: The `TryFind` method returns an `option`, which is either going to be `None` or `Some x` where, in this case, `x` is a record of type `GeneralInfo`. Options are their own type, and do not have a `.GrossIncome` property. You have already encountered this problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884960/how-to-use-map-tryfind and Thomas Corbière gave you very good advice: you need to read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/ and understand it before you'll know how to use TryFind correctly.

Comment: yeah thats all great, but the only reason I posted this is because I intend to use an option type as you can see I have defined GrossIncome as an `int Option`. This question has nothing to do with the question linked above and the option page is of no help. I would not post such a similar question. I just need to know how to select a record from the GeneralInfo using Map.TryFind. Nothing to do with how to deal with an option, as I have defined the record as an option type.

Comment: @ThomasCorbière I have updated the question.

Comment: @JohnLaw use `Option.map`

Comment: `generalMap.TryFind(state) |> Option.map(fun s -> s.GrossIncome)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`Option.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/option.map%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
generalMap.TryFind(state) |> Option.map(fun s -> s.GrossIncome)
```